# Undefined control sequence \href in the mentioned code

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

By the following code sample, I receive the error "undefined control sequence \href". Why?

```
\documentclass[dvips,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.25in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.5in}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf {Demography}}
\author{Jack Dov}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{}

  \href{https://www.prospectmagazine.co.uk/magazine/theres-nothing-new-about-post-truth-politics}{\color{blue}recent}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: aside from the `\color` error your first two lines are contradictory. `\documentclass[dvips,12pt]{article}\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` you only want `dvips` option if you are _not_ using pdftex and you only want the `pdftex` option if you are using pdftex. delete both these options as the correct option will be automatically supplied in each case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...toreSpaceFactor \Hy@LinkMath \color 
                                                  {blue}recent\Hy@xspace@end...
l.21 ...t-post-truth-politics}{\color{blue}recent}

?
```

which shows the undefined command is `\color` as you have not loaded the `color` or `xcolor` package.

Comment: if your editor only shows the error message that you quote that is a misfeature of your editor, probably this: https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/